# Link from PHP page to open in a fixed size window

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink

I am trying to create a link inside of a PHP search results page that allows the user to click "open" and have a 296 x 278 window come up where more information is displayed.

All of the PHP works correctly, i am just having trouble opening a link from the PHP page and having it open in a fixed sized window.

I have tried multiple different javascripts but i cannot seem to get it working correctly when trying to impliment it into my $output statement.

This is my current $output statement that i would like to open in the fixed sized window. It currently opens the page in a new tab.

```
$output .= "<tr><td>Drag & Drop:</b></td><td><a href='details/" . $row['idrop'] . "' target='_blank'>" . " Open " . "</a>";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try "window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)"

Comment: where is the javascript you have used for new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$output .= "<tr><td>Drag & Drop:</b></td><td><a href='#_' target='_blank' onclick=\"open_me('details/{$row['idrop']}');\">Open</a>";
```

aand here is your JS function

```
<script>
function open_me(h_rf)
{
    window.open(h_rf,'_blank','width=296,height=278,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');

    return false;
}
</script>
```

read more about this function from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Works like a charm! Only one strange thing, when i click "open" it opens the new fixed sized window perfectly, but also opens another one of my PHP search results pages in a new tab.

Comment: basically, you need to stop 'href' of 'a' tag from working. I think its #_. Also, add "return false;" at the end of the JS function

Comment: Removing "target='_blank'" from the output statement did the trick. Works absolutely perfectly. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @RaheelHasan you shouldn't use w3schools as reference, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) is much better...
See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) to know about it...

Answer (score 1):

Include this small javascript snippet in your code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=278,width=296');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

</script>
```

And for your php $output variable

```
$output .= "<tr><td>Drag & Drop:</b></td><td><a href=""  onclick='return popitup(\"details/" . $row['idrop'] . "\")'>" . " Open " . "</a>";
```

Check the escape characters before executing this code.